# Fortify Scan, Java print() String, Cross-Site Scripting

Tags: java, xss, fortify

Anyone know a fix that will make Fortify Scan happy and not flag the "print(x)" below as vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting?

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        print(x);
        println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that this tool is using tons of context information to make that decision. You don't give us even a glimpse of that. How do you think we would be able to help with such input?

Comment: likely x is coming from some http request parameter, and this PrintWriter-looking class is writing to the http response stream.

Comment: MeBigFatGuy is correct.  The class extends java.io.PrintWriter and is generating output for a javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.

Answer (score 0):

Fortify believes the input to this is tainted (maybe because it comes from a parameters) and is looking for a routine which validates or encodes the value to prevent XSS.

Note that validation should be done preferably as a white list validation, and encoding should be done at the time of output when you know the context of the encoding (HTML attribute?  Javascript?)

Its not clear if you have enough context in this routine to do either of those.  So you may need to do this somewhere more appropriate in the data flow.  You'll also need to tell Fortify (via a rule) that the routine you used for validation or encoding is a cleansing routine for XSS.

Then - Fortify will be happy, and your code will be safer.